# Alert Dialog - how to implement Cancel and Okay button

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I have got this Alert Dialog which has these two buttons (Ok and Cancel). I want to know how I go about implementing it.

So When you click on the cancel button it should close the alert dialog and return back to the fragment I am currently on. And if I click on the Ok button it should replace the current alert dialog and place it with another one.

this is my code below for the confimration. java file;

```
public class confirmation extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View theDIalog = inf.inflate(R.layout.example_xml, null);
    builder.setView(theDIalog);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();



    theDIalog.findViewById(R.id.makeaTransferOk).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Okay button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    theDIalog.findViewById(R.id.makeaTransferCancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return dialog;
}
}
```

this is my code for the example_xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffc0c0c0">

<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:id="@+id/makeaTransferCancel"/>

<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:id="@+id/makeaTransferOk"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please could someone help me

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error saying "Cannot resolve method 'dismiss()' "

Comment: The cancel button works, so i changed the code to dialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code for the functionality you have mentioned above:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //put your code that needed to be executed when okay is clicked
            dialog.cancel();


            }
            });
            builder1.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
```

Comment: is this new dialog fragment or am I updating the current one I have ? it's just I don't full understand it

Comment: In my given code: ('put your code that needed to be executed..')
Add the code/logics that will create a new dialog.

Actually you have to repeat this section inside of the setPositiveButton() section

Answer (score 3):

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("your message ");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss(); //<-- change it with ur code
                }
            } );
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            } );

    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.setPositiveButton(text, new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton(text, new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        }).create();
```